# Using char-set in Scheme

Tags: list, function, scheme, character, punctuation

This function must find `!"#%&'()*,-./:;?@[\]_{}` characters in given list. If any those characters are found at least one time then it must return true. But i can not find proper predefined function for this aim.

```
(define (is-symbol lst)
  (if (null? (car lst))
  #f
  (if (char-set:punctuation (car lst)) #t
           (is-symbol (cdr lst)))
  ))

(is-symbol '(#\A #\b #\t #\R #\f 3 5 4 7 8 9 #\A #\G #\w #\q $ & ?))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I pulled the text of your question above the code snippet to make the question easier to read - this is a technique called Bottom Line Up Front. There is a [great article about how to write good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please consider having a read of it and editing your question to be clearer about what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`char-punctuation?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._char-punctuation~3f%29%29):

```
(define (is-symbol? lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((char-punctuation? (car lst)) #t)
        (else (is-symbol (cdr lst)))))
```

Or even simpler:

```
(define (is-symbol? lst)
  (ormap char-punctuation? lst))
```

Comment: I use DrRacket in Advance Student language mode. It gives this error : char-punctuation? : this function is not defined

Comment: Change the language then, use #racket . Otherwise you'd have to implement the procedure yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `char-set:punctuation`, which looks like SRFI-14. The corresponding membership predicate is `char-set-contains?`.